# Firefox/XUL: coords of DOM Element on display

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul, xulrunner

I'm developing Firefox extension. For some statistics I need actual **display** coordinates of DOM Element inside [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XUL/browser).

I can get coordinates of:

1. Required DOM Element inside viewport by calling it's [`getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect) (this takes scrolling into account, perfect).
2. The Window (`ChromeWindow`) itself by checking it's `screenX` & `screenY` properties.

But when I call `getBoundingClientRects()` of [browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/XUL/browser), I get it coordinates excluding the size of window frame & borders drawn by system (tested on Mac). How to also count their (borders & frames) size independently for different operating systems?

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found comment inside sources of Firefox that [it's not possible](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/annotate/50d25e083421/browser/base/content/browser.js#l917).

Answer (score 1):

How about [window.screenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.screenX) or [window.mozInnerScreenX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.mozInnerScreenX)? Respectively screenY, etc.

If that doesn't work, you could probably use [js-ctypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes) to call OS-functions, which i guess are able to let you calculate the border size. On Windows you'd use GetWindowRect and GetClientRect as explained in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431470/window-border-width-and-height-in-win32-how-do-i-get-it). No idea how this is possible in OSX though, but there surely is a way ...

Good luck!