# How to get the real height of title bar with c++

Tags: c++, winapi, getsystemmetrics

Actually I find there is a same demand post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431470/window-border-width-and-height-in-win32-how-do-i-get-it). But I find some problem still, so I have to post another question here.

If I use [snipaste](https://www.snipaste.com/) to capture the toolbar. I can know the real title bar is `28` like this
[image]

But if I use the method in that post like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <wtypes.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I will just get `23`. Is there any thing I have missed? Or the `28` actually contain other portion besides the title bar? What can I do to find the real height of title bar with c++.

Comment: Maybe it is y caption + y frame?

Comment: @VTT `SM_CYSIZEFRAME` is just `4` pixels..

Comment: There is also SM_CXPADDEDBORDER, border padding for captioned Windows. I've had to include this in similar calculations myself.

Comment: But why not `AdjustWindowRect`?

Comment: @MikkelK. Is there no `SM_CYPADDEDBORDER`? I think you can arrange it as a answer for reading. Thanks anyway. :)

Comment: @DanielSęk Sorry, I cannot realize it can do this..

Comment: If you want height of whole top border: `RECT r={0}; AdjustWindowRect(&r,window_styles,FALSE);title_height=-r.top;`. Styles could be for example `WS_CAPTION|WS_THICKFRAME`

Answer (score 4):

Not *precisely* what you asked, but I often find this a useful metric:

```
int FindExtraWindowHeight(HWND h)
{
  RECT w, c;
  GetWindowRect(h, &w);
  GetClientRect(h, &c);
  return (w.bottom - w.top) - (c.bottom - c.top);
}
```

The difference between the window and the client area. So this will give you the title bar height + the border thickness.