# Is it possible to get height of window's title bar?

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am working on some code about capturing mouse location. I have a frame created by using wxWidgets, and I am working on an issue which I need to get the title bar height. Is there a good way to get the size of title bar?

Here is a simple illustration of what I need: [image: title bar height (h)]

Comment: i think this might be the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/431548/11118883

Comment: Did you just assume that the title bar always sits on top of your window? [Big mistake](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLWM#/media/File%3AFLWM_Screenshot.png).

Comment: I assume that the title bar always sits on top. @n.m.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

wxWidgets provides a mechanism for this (and much else beside) called `wxSystemSettings::GetMetric`.

```
static int wxSystemSettings::GetMetric(wxSystemMetric index, wxWindow* win = NULL);
```

You can retrieve 'global' values by leaving `win` as `NULL` or you can pass in a specific window.

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_system_settings.html#aa18e3b5794dc4193c4b0668d28d4933a

The metric you probably want is `wxSYS_CAPTION_Y`.

https://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/settings_8h.html#a0f2b19d7a3717cdbef5a04cb05ab8f26

Comment: `wxSYS_CAPTION_Y` is the thing I am looking for. Thanks for the great documented response.

Answer (score 0):

It should be the `y` coordinate of what `wxWindow::GetClientAreaOrigin()` returns.

Comment: Both of the `x` and `y` values of `wxWindow::GetClientAreaOrigin()` returns zero, then I couldn't get the right thing.