# What is the point of the zero flag WS_OVERLAPPED in Win32?

Tags: winapi

According to Win32 official docs:

[Window Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles)

> | Constant name | Constant value | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | WS_OVERLAPPED | 0x00000000L | The window is an overlapped window. An overlapped window has a title bar and a border. Same as the WS_TILED style. |

What is the point of a zero flag?  In C programming, it doesn't make sense to me.  Only non-zero values make sense for additive/accumulative flagging.

Comment: Why only non-zero? [MessageBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) flags come to mind: there are MB_OK = 0, MB_DEFBUTTON1 = 0, MB_APPLMODAL = 0. if you have not specified any of MB_DEFBUTTON2, MB_DEFBUTTON3 or MB_DEFBUTTON4 then it has to be MB_DEFBUTTON1 and you can save a few bits just in case, given you will need to introduce additional API in case you run out of bits in the flag mask.

Comment: And also, probably even more useful, have flags defined as zero, allows skipping them, i.e. you don't need to specify, say, the default button or modality of the dialog if you just want the default behavior.

Comment: No special bits set, you get a normal window.

Comment: @HansPassant Your comment makes perfect sense.  In effect, "use all defaults".  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I guess one way to look at it is that `OVERLAPPED` is the default style, unless you modify it with those additive flags. This #define gives you a readable way to express this in code, for example:

```
CreateWindowA("some_class", NULL, WS_OVERLAPPED, ...)
```

That's clearer than just passing 0. It makes a lot less sense if you start combining it with other flags, of course.