# What is the difference between WS_OVERLAPPED/WS_TILED and WS_CAPTION?

Tags: winapi, win32gui, user32

What is the difference between [WS_OVERLAPPED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) / [WS_TILED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles) and [WS_CAPTION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-styles)?

What is the difference between setting and not setting `WS_OVERLAPPED`?

Comment: `WS_OVERLAPPED` is the same as `WS_TILED` but you shouldn't compare `WS_OVERLAPPED` with `WS_CAPTION` (even if it's implied): a window is overlapped if it's not `WS_CHILD` (but a child window might - or might not - have `WS_CAPTION` and `WS_BORDER` - which is implied by `WS_CAPTION`). Note: as far as I can remember...

Comment: Both `WS_OVERLAPPED` as well as `WS_TILED` evaluate to zero. There is no difference between setting and not setting either of those flags. They are just named constants to let readers of your code know: *"We're requesting a standard window with nothing special added."*

Comment: Related: [What is the point of the zero flag WS_OVERLAPPED in Win32?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74761415/1889329)

Comment: Window styles have not aged well over the decades.  Using tiled windows made sense in Windows version 1, it does not anymore.